# How to install OpenMPI with exact version of shared files?

Tags: ubuntu, openmpi

**Scenario**

I am working with third party library *TCLB* to do my Master Thesis in the field of computational physic. As I know it depends on few other libraries and packages such as *R*, *python2.7*, *singularity* and finally *openmpi*. I installed openMPI: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall openmpi10-bin libopenmpi-dev`.

**Problem**

Unfortunately library docs are not always helpful. I have solved many problems and cannot deal with the last one:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libhdf5_openmpi.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I used command `find / -name libhdf5_openmpi.so\* 2>/dev/null` and find out that I have similar file: `libhdf5_openmpi.so.103`.

I tried to rename the file from 103 to 10. But next I received similar error for:
`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpi.so.12`. I have on my PC file: `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpi.so.40` and for pair: `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpi_cxx.so.40`(I have this one)  `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpi_cxx.so.1`(needed this one). After all this deoes't work. It is not so easy to cheat this way.

So my question is: How to install open mpi to has files which I need.